Telerik.Reporting v18 with .Net ReportsController - front end ReportViewer cannot resolve the reports
Working with Telerik.Reporting 18.1.24.514 in our .Net 8.0 project in Visual Studio 2022.
In our old framework 4.6 project, Our ReportsController.cs was calling into a separate Reports project which contained all the report designs, etc. And front-end Angular component used the telerikReportViewerTemplate.html viewer.
So, we've upgrade our main API project to .Net 8.0 - but I want the new ReportsController.cs to call into the old Reports framework project (i.e. upgrading all the Reports to Telerik v18 Core is a problem regarding the old Telerik Charts lib, which is obsolete now https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/report-items/chart-(obsolete) ).
In the new .Net 8 project, I'm able to set a breakpoint - but the front end always throws an error:
Unable to get report parameters. Report 'SynReports.ReportCatalog' cannot be resolved.

Here's the .Net 8 ReportsController.cs


using System.Web.Http;
using Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi;
using System.Web;
using Telerik.Reporting.Cache.File;
using Telerik.Reporting.Services;

namespace SyneWAPI.Controllers
{
    [AllowCrossSiteJson]
    [RoutePrefix("api/reports")]
    public class ReportsController : ReportsControllerBase
    {

        static readonly ReportServiceConfiguration configurationInstance =
        new ReportServiceConfiguration
        {
            HostAppId = "HarApp",
            ReportSourceResolver = new UriReportSourceResolver(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports"))
                .AddFallbackResolver(new TypeReportSourceResolver()),
            Storage = new FileStorage(),
        };

        public ReportsController()
        {
            ReportServiceConfiguration = configurationInstance;
        }
    }
}



and Program.cs


using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Telerik.Reporting.Services;
using Telerik.Reporting.Cache.File;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services
    .AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true;
        options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<StringOutputFormatter>();
    })
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
// TODO: CORS will have to be updated
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
     {
         builder.AllowAnyHeader();
         builder.AllowAnyMethod();
         builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
     });
});

        // Configure dependencies for ReportsController.
        builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IReportServiceConfiguration>(sp =>
            new ReportServiceConfiguration
            {
                ReportingEngineConfiguration = sp.GetService<IConfiguration>(),        
                HostAppId = "Harmony",
                Storage = new FileStorage(),
                ReportSourceResolver =
                    new UriReportSourceResolver(
                        System.IO.Path.Combine(sp.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>().ContentRootPath, "~\\SynReports")
                        )
            });


builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
    c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
    c.IgnoreObsoleteActions();
    c.IgnoreObsoleteProperties();
    c.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName);
});



var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();



I think the kicker might be this line here: System.IO.Path.Combine(sp.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>().ContentRootPath, "~\\SynReports")
And you can see that SynReport referenced here in the WAPICore project

On the front-end, our stats.component.ts:


export class StatisticsComponent {
    currentPatient: any;
    serviceUrl: string;
    reportSource: any;


    telerikTemplateUrl: string;
    viewerContainerStyle = {
        position: 'relative',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        ['font-family']: 'ms sans serif'
    };
    
    constructor(private readonly appSession: AppSession, private readonly config: AppConfigService) {
        this.serviceUrl = "https://hardevapp01.topsyn.com/har63/api/reports";
        this.telerikTemplateUrl = "assets/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-18.1.24.514.html";

        this.reportSource = {
            report: "SynReports.ReportCatalog",
            parameters: {
                UserID: "TheUserID",
                SessionID: "TheSessionID",
                RootUrl: "",
            },
        };
    }
}



The HTML template:


<tr-viewer    
    [containerStyle]="viewerContainerStyle"
    [serviceUrl]="serviceUrl"
    [reportSource]="reportSource"
    [viewMode]="'INTERACTIVE'"
    [scaleMode]="'SPECIFIC'"
    [pageMode]="'SINGLE_PAGE'"
    [scale]="1.0"
    [templateUrl]="telerikTemplateUrl"
    [parameters]="{
        editors: {
            multiSelect: 'COMBO_BOX',
            singleSelect: 'COMBO_BOX'
        }
    }"
>
</tr-viewer>







We did get over the first hurdle.
Our WAPICore project did not have the project reference to the old "SynReports" project - so the SynReports.dll was never in the bin folder.
We have a new issue when launching the actual reports now. It's not using the old Telerik framework, and so it's crashing out on all the Telerik.Reporting.Charting libs.
